# preg_match_all print *all* matches

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I need to print all matches using preg_match_all.

```
$search = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo $match[0];
    echo $match[1];
    echo $match[...];
}
```

The problem is I don't know how many matches there in my string, and even if I knew and if it was 1000 that would be pretty dumb to type all those `$match[]`'s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$match[0]`, `$match[1]`, etc., items are not the individual matches, they're the "captures".

Regardless of how many matches there are, the number of entries in `$matches` is constant, because it's based on what you're searching *for*, not the results.  There's always at least one entry, plus one more for each pair of capturing parentheses in the search pattern.

For example, if you do:

```
$matches = array();
$search = preg_match_all("/\D+(\d+)/", "a1b12c123", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Matches will have only two items, even though three matches were found.  `$matches[0]` will be an array containing "a1", "b12" and "c123" (the entire match for each item) and `$matches[1]` will contain only the first capture for each item, i.e., "1", "12" and "123".

I think what you want is something more like:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    echo $match;
}
```

Which will print out the first capture expression from each matched string.

Answer (score 0):

Does [print_r($matches)](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) give you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop recursively. This example requires SPL and PHP 5.1+ via [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/recursivearrayiterator):

```
foreach( new RecursiveArrayIterator( $matches ) as $match )
    print $match;
```